# "Expression was too complex" initializing a Set from an Array literal

Tags: ios, swift

I've read a bunch of questions here about **"Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"** errors and they boil down to overloaded operators (particularly +) and type inference take a long time to compile. And the answer is usually to indeed break up the offending expression into pieces or to be explicit with the type. My problem seems different.

```
let someSet: Set<String> = [
    "aardvark",
    "aardvarks",
    "abaci",
    "aback",
// ... 81,000 more words ...
    "zygote",
    "zygotes",
    "zygotic",
    "zymurgies",
    "zymurgy",
]
```

I would like prepopulate a Set at compile time instead of runtime to save time loading, plus this seemed like a simple way to get a lot of data into my app. This file compiles for 10 minutes (with 3 processes using 100% CPU) before getting the above error. I don't see any expressions to break up and I was explicit about the type. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large literals just don't quite work in Swift. If you want such a big literal, you need to store it in a file and read it. In this case, I recommend using the JSON format.

Create a json file named myData.json or whatever and write your literal:

```
[
    "aardvark",
    "aardvarks",
    "abaci",
    "aback",
// ... 81,000 more words ...
    "zygote",
    "zygotes",
    "zygotic",
    "zymurgies",
    "zymurgy"
]
```

Fortunately, JSON array syntax is almost the same as Swift array literals!

Now you can read the file like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myData", withExtension: "json"), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let stringArray = try? decoder.decode([String].self, from: data) {
        let someSet = Set(stringArray)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the words in a JSON file and import it into the set upon app start.